# WordPress: Trying to fetch one row of data and set into array

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use the Wordpress built-in functions to search and retrieve one row of data and place it in a string, but I get "object of class stdclass could not be converted to string.." error.
Code I'm using is:

```
<?php
$zip = $_GET['z'];
//primary key is $zip   
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_main_placename_zip WHERE _Zip_Code = $zip");

$array = json_decode(json_encode($results), True);

echo $array[0];
echo $array[1];
echo $array[2];
//echo $results[1];
//echo $results[2];
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks, again, for your help guys, but I just cannot seem to get this to work (either gazz or Herman's).  I can get this to work outside of WordPress, but in this particular situation, I need to get this to work inside of Wordpress aand set each variable to a shortcode so I can add the variables within a page/post.  I tried the 'ARRAY_N' method from the Codex, but it retiurns NULL,  My column names are: _Zip_Code Latitude Longitude Zoom _Tel1 _Tel2 _Placename

Comment: Sample representative data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lWpHTnWoa8yaGmHB5ZXUsOgSFbX_9FHeAtYqFGO6ke4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The object to which you are [`printing`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is an object, in this case

```
$array[0];
```

Return an object.. example

Error : http://codepad.org/iGbZcN6W

```php
$code = '[{"id":2,"name":"Bob"},{"id":3,"name":"Maria"}]';
$parse = json_decode($code);

//"object of class stdclass could not be converted to string..
echo $parse[0];

//prints Bob
echo $parse[0]->name
```

If you want to print the entire object you can use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

```
//prints object
echo var_dump($parse[0]);
```

check if http://codepad.org/EwIUbnIU

Revised code

```php
$zip = $_GET['z'];
//primary key is $zip   
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_main_placename_zip WHERE _Zip_Code = $zip");

$array = json_decode(json_encode($results));

//_zip_code field
echo $array[0]->_Zip_Code;
// or all fields
var_dump($array[1]);
```

I hope I've helped :)

Comment: This is what happens: echo $array[0]->_Zip_Code; returns nothing  var_dump($array[1]); returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

Revised code

$zip = $_GET['z'];

global $wpdb;

//Use get_row(); for single row

$results = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_main_placename_zip WHERE _Zip_Code = $zip"); 
$objasarray = json_decode(json_encode($results));

$zipcode = $objasarray['_Zip_Code'];

I think this may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

replace your query with 
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_main_placename_zip WHERE _Zip_Code = '".$zip."'",ARRAY_N);

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted out.  This works posting un case someone runs across the same issue:

```
$zip = $_GET['z'];

//primary key is $zip   
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_roof_main_placename_zip WHERE _Zip_Code = '".$zip."'",ARRAY_A);

$array = json_decode(json_encode($results));


echo $array[0]->_Zip_Code;
$zipcode = $array[0]->_Zip_Code;
echo $zipcode;
```

Thanks all, for your help!
-Brian